# Mongo db not returning result after sending a post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new too expressjs and mongodb. I am trying to add data to a collection in my database using a post request in express but it is now working. Here is my code.

````
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(
        client => {
            console.log("Connected to the database")
            const db = client.db('star-wars')
            const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes')

            app.post('quotes/', (req, res) => {
                quotesCollection.insertOne(req.body).then(
                    result => {
                        console.log(result)
                        res.redirect('/')
                    }
                ).catch(error => console.error(error))
            })

        }
    ).catch(error => console.error(error))```

It is meant to log result back to the console but nothing is happening
````

Comment: cant you edit your question by adding the post method you using to send data i.e the form html code or the curl request

Answer (score 0):

Routes should start with `/quotes` not `quotes/`.For that your app cant access the post request.

Comment: I think you are making an empty request to the post.

Comment: Not at all, i'm sending data from a form using the POST method @marshal